# Cannot assign [...] must be a "CustomUser" instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am building a Django application with a form, where a logged-in user, a composer, is able to submit a composition they wrote. For this reason, I'd like the 'composer' field of this composition to be already filled with their name, read-only.

I have created a custom user model and linked it via the AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings.

When I create a new composition via the admin interface I have a drop-down list for the composer (showing the available users), and I can successfully create a new composition. While doing the same thing via the front-end, though, I get a 'Cannot assign "'1'": "Composition.composer" must be a "CustomUser" instance.' error.

I've also tried with get_user_model() instead of 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL' in the Composition model, have tried with all the different ways of gathering the active user, for example putting request.user in a variable 'activeuser' in the context and setting the form manually with value="{{ activeuser }}", all to no avail.

If I put `active_user = request.user.somethingwrong` in my views.py (`def composition_create_view(request)`) I get a `'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'something'` error upon submitting the form, which tells me that I am actually getting the CustomUser object. Am I wrong?

myapp/models.py:

```
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120) # max_length = required
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    composer = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

users/models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager


class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    pass


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

settings.py:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'`

myapp/views.py:

```
    active_user = request.user
    form = CompositionForm(request.POST or None, initial={'composer' : active_user})
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = CompositionForm()
    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "compositions/composition_create.html", context)
```

myapp/form.py:

```
#from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CompositionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title       = forms.CharField(label='Title',
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your title"}))
    description = forms.CharField(
                        required=False,
                        widget=forms.Textarea(
                                attrs={
                                    "placeholder": "Your description",
                                }
                            )
                        )
    composer = forms.CharField(label='Composer', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                    "readonly": "readonly",
                                }
                            )
                        )



    class Meta:
        model = Composition
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'composer',
        ]
```

I expect to save the composition after hitting save; instead, I get the 'Cannot assign "[whatever user I'm logged in]": "Composition.composer" must be a "CustomUser" instance.' error

Comment: The composer field should be a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) passed a queryset of your CustomUser model

Comment: Or better yet, don't define a custom "composer" field and just set the readonly widget in the Meta of the model form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets

Comment: @IainShelvington THANK YOU!!! I've been battling with this all day and just by commenting the 'composer' field in forms.py and adding `'widgets={'composer': forms.TextInput(attrs={"readonly": "readonly"})}'` to my `class Meta:` in `forms.py` the issue vanished. I'm not able to set your answer as the right answer, maybe it's because my account is not 'pro' enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @IainShelvington, I solved commenting the `composer` field in `forms.py` and adding

```
widgets={'composer': forms.TextInput(attrs={"readonly": "readonly"})}
```

to my `class Meta:`.